# MVC 5 integer validation when entering a non integer

Tags: popup, integer, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-validation, asp.net-mvc-views

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application, and have a question in regards to validating a integer value in a view.

I have a model with the following variable:

```
public int integerValue { get; set; }
```

If I enter a string value in the view for this model, I am getting an alert pop up that says:

```
Please enter a number.
```

This is not a normal validation message, and instead appears to be related to the browser.

My question is this: Is it possible to override this alert pop up to instead have the usual validation message beneath the input field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will be because Mvc has output an editor with input[type=number].

If you can live without the html5 spinner controls, you can try adding

```
 [DataType(DataType = DataType.Text)]
```

to the property in question.

Or you can try

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.{YourProperty}, new { htmlAttributes= new{ @type="text"}})
```

Comment: 'DataTypeAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments